# Segfault when accessing static array from base class

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I've got something like this:

```
template <typename Item>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(Item* arr, int size):
        m_data(arr),
        m_size(size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = Item();
        }
    }
private:
    Item* m_data;
    int m_size;
};

template<typename Item, unsigned int Size=0>

class Derived
{
public:
    Derived():
        Base<Item>(m_storage, Size)
    {
    }
private:
    Item m_storage[Size]
};
```

So the reason I'm doing this is that I'm trying to initialize storage for use in the base class (a coverity complaint) and I've realized this is probably the wrong way to go about this, but I'm just wondering why am I getting a seg fault when the base class tries to write into the array. I'm initializing a size 3 derived with string as its item type and it segfaults in the first iteration of the for loop.

Also note, I think this is probably not the way to solve my coverity issue, and I have another solution for it, but I'm just really curious as to why it would seg fault since it should be able to access that static data in the array.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because when the Base constructor is being called, the derived object does not exist yet.

Comment: When `arr[i] = Item();` runs, `arr[i]` must be already constructed. But this is not the case in your code: `m_storage`, and thus its elements, get constructed only after `Base` constructor runs.

Comment: It is possible to make this work with another base class, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is order of initialization.

This statement:

```
arr[i] = Item();
```

Assumes that the item on the left has already been initialized and its lifetime started. i.e. An assignment operator is a ssigning to an object that has already had its constructor called.

In your situation this is not true.

If we look at the derived object:

```
class Derived
{
public:
    Derived():
        Base<Item>(m_storage, Size)   // Here you are calling the base class
                                      // constructor where the above assignment
                                      // is actually being done.

      // But there is an implied initialization of the array
      // m_storage (that happens here).
      //
      // Before this point the memory for this array of object of
      // type <Item> has not been initialized (ie. no constructors
      // have been called).
      //
      // Yet you are using the array in the base class constructor
      // above.
      //
      // Note the initialization of this object done automatically
      // does a very similar thing to what you are doing in the base
      // class. i.e. Every member of the array is initialized using
      // the default constructor.
    {
    }
private:
    Item m_storage[Size]
};
```